# Click Lock for external mouse on OS X Sierra

Tags: osx, mouse

I have OS X Sierra and I use an external USB mouse. I would like to be able to somehow click a mouse button and it "click lock" (emulate me holding down the mouse button for a length of time).

Windows has exactly the feature I'm looking for:

[image]